# Learning Jekyll requirements

Tags: jekyll

I wanted to learn Jekyll mainly for designing websites and blogs.

What are the necessary required skills that I should have before I can start digging into Jekyll/

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today I learned Jekyll. It's pretty straigt forward!

The minimum prerequisites are knowledge of HTML and CSS. Nice to have but not required before you start is some knowledge about [Liquid](http://liquidmarkup.org/) Jekyll's templating engine.

I used [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/home/)'s own tutorial, that David already pointed out and read through the first few pages. Then I got hands on with it by following the quick start instructions from their homepage:

```
gem install jekyll
jekyll new my-awesome-site
cd my-awesome-site
jekyll serve
# => Now browse to http://localhost:4000
```

Installing it on my Mac worked fine with the pre installed [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/de/) and its packagemanager [RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/) on my Mac OS X 10.9. I already installed [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and it's packagemanager [npm](https://www.npmjs.org/) before, but i haven't seen where it's needed but maybe somewhere under the hood.

From here I inspected the demo package, read a bit in the docs and googled my way through till I had a working site build by Jekyll.

Have fun!

P.S. For the posts and sites I [refreshed my knowledge about the markdown syntax.](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)

Comment: Thank you David-Jacquel, rudy-velthuis and last but not least @wedi. Fortunately I have been using markdown for some time. The next target is liquid templating engine and then Jekyll.

I'm concerned that I have is that I use *Windows* and unfortunately do not own a Mac. From what I have learned that getting Jekyll running on Windows is cumbersome but not impossible therefore I'm going for it!

Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

Well except html, css and javascript, you just [have to learn Jekyll itself](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/home/) it's really easy.

Go for it !

Comment: One could use Textile or Markdown instead of HTML. I started with pure HTML and CSS, but now I prefer Textile and SCSS. @Pali: once you have things set up, it is very easy to add content, no matter if you prefer HTML, Markdown or Textile.